# GridView cell text formating for long text

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is there any property in GridView of asp.net to show big/Long text data as like 
if my data is "My name is Raj and i am indian" and this text will display in cell of gridview like
My name is Ra...
and when user mousehover it show full text in tooltip

Is there any predefined property in asp.net gridview or i need to write manual code for it?
Any suggestions are appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I've done this, I've used a TemplateField and custom code for it e.g.

Markup:

```
<asp:Templatefield>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="MyLabel" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Templatefield>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void GridView_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Get hold of the string we want to bind
    DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
    string longString = rowView["LongString"].ToString();

    Label MyLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("MyLabel");

    // If the string is less than 20 characters, just bind it
    if (longString.Length() < 20)
    {
        MyLabel.Text = longString;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the string is more than 20 characters, bind the first
        // 17 characters plus an ellipsis, and bind the whole string
        // into the tooltip
        MyLabel.Text = String.Format("{0}...", longString.SubString(0,17);
        MyLabel.Tooltip = longString;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but string longString = rowView["LongString"].ToString(); this line show me error object reference not set to instance ....                                          could you please tell me why my code  string ToolTipString = e.Row.Cells[2].Text; alway give "" in my datatable which i trying to bind is not empty in column 2 but then also it show me ""

Comment: How can I use this in my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979966/how-to-set-ellipses-on-a-column-data-if-it-exceeds-more-than-a-set-record. What is `LongString` and `MyLabel` defined?