# How to set ellipses on a column data if it exceeds more than a set record

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to set ellipses on a column data

I have the following `BoundField` in my GridView:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Provider" HeaderText="Provider" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideText" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
```

It is populated from a sql query and displays like this (the smudged out data is all the provider returned from the result):

[image]

I am populating the data from code-behind (partial code):

```
int rowcounter = 0;
SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems(oQuery);
foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
{
    try
    {
        rowcounter++;
        string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item["Guideline"].ToString());
        string location = item["Location"].ToString().Replace("#", "\n").TrimStart(';');
        string specialty = item["Specialty"].ToString().Replace("#", "\n").TrimStart(';');
        string topic = item["Topic"].ToString().Replace("#", "\n").TrimStart(';');
        strTopNum = topic.Split(';')[0]; //gets the number for the topic index to display it in a button
        //MessageBox.Show(strTopNum);
        //var btn = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.IButtonControl)                             
        string provider = item["Provider"].ToString().Replace("#", "\n").TrimStart(';');
        Results.Rows.Add(item["ID"], location.TrimEnd(';'), specialty.TrimEnd(';'), topic.Split(';')[1], provider.TrimEnd(';'), item["Summary"].ToString(), item["Guideline"].ToString());
        //.Split(';')[1] for topic
        //Results.Rows.Add(item["ID"], item["Location"].ToString().Replace("#", "\n").TrimStart(';').TrimEnd(';'), item["Specialty"].ToString().Replace("#", "\n").TrimStart(';').TrimEnd(';'), item["Topic"].ToString().Replace("#", "\n"), item["Provider"].ToString().Replace("#", "\n"), item["Summary"].ToString(), item["Guideline"].ToString());
        //strNum[item] = topic.Split(';')[0];

        Results.DefaultView.Sort = Results.Columns[3].ColumnName + " ASC";
        Results = Results.DefaultView.ToTable(true);


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = ex.Message;
    }

}
```

How can I modify the code so for the PROVIDER column only the first 3 records are displayed, followed by `...` if there are more records returned?

I used the following CSS but it didn't work for me:

```
.hideText {
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;        
}
```

Updated to this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProvider" Text="Provider" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPro" Text='<%#Eval("Provider")%>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("Provider")%>' CssClass="hideText" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

.hideText  {
    width:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
 }
```

The TD expands out very long and the HTML source shows this:

[image]

Comment: Can they modify that value in the datagrid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`text-overflow:ellipsis;` only works if the the following properties are true:

The element's width must be specified.
The element must have `overflow:hidden` and `white-space:nowrap` set. Change your `css` like below

```
.hideText  {
    width:120px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
 }
```

Here is the working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uh0yf1wr/2/)

**Update:**

Here is your complete `TemplateField` definition. Define a `div` within the `TemplateField` and decorate with the css properties for ellipsis.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Provider Name">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <div style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
               <asp:Label ID="lblEllipsis" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Provider") %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("Provider") %>'></asp:Label>
          </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is how it looks like when I tried this in a gridview locally.

[image]

Comment: Awesome that works. Because it is a DataField, how would I allow the user to hover over and display an alert with the full text?>

Comment: I would go with a `templatecolumn` with a `label` instead of a `BoundColumn`. The Label's properties will be `Text='<%#Eval("Provider")' Tooltip='<%#Eval("Provider")%>'`

Comment: I am testing it out now. Thank you. In that case, I can use JQuery/CSS to customize the tooltip :)

Comment: I updated my question to what I did but it is displaying everything... and showing a horizontal scrollbar which extends out very far.

Comment: +1 - I found this answer useful by the way.  Why can the data not be shown in the markup?  Any solution to show full provider listing is going to have to show that information in the HTML somewhere or else you will have to complicate things quite a bit.

Comment: This would be great except mine is doing something awkward! :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Sorry I was out for lunch. Try my updated code and let me know if still doesn't work for you.

Comment: @DennisR... Thank you :) I will test it out. You are too kind! So just add the TemplateField you posted and comment out what I currently have?

Comment: This is great answer on two account. First, it is detailed. Second, instead of applying directly to the BoundField, you have added it to DIV in a TemplateField. I previously added it directly to BoundField after hints from other SO post. However, it breaks bottom line of the row and some other CSS issues. 
This resolves that. !! Awesome !

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be modifying this where you could not store it back to the database anyway so I would just handle it like this unless they need an option to then see the entirety of the data.

I did all this c# in this editor so there might be slight problems, lets call it psuedo code!

```
string provider = item["Provider"].ToString().Replace("#", "\n").TrimStart(';');
string[] providerListing = provider.Split(new[]{";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
if(providerListing.Length > 3)
{
    //Make an array of the first 3 providers
    string[] firstProviders = new string[3];
    Array.Copy(providerListing, firstProviders, 3);
    //Reconcatenate with ; and add ellipsis
    provider = String.Join(";",firstProviders)+"...";
}
```

If they do need to see the entirety of the data I would add another column called FullProviders or something like that to query.

Comment: So let's say I want to then allow the user to hover over and display the full list in an alert or something?

Comment: That's where you would have to have the FullProviders Column which is hidden but then you handle displaying it when you have to.

Comment: Thank you. So I know you said it is psuedo code but the `providerListing.Count` is not found :/

Comment: It is Length there instead of Count.

Comment: One more thing... `Array.Copy(providerListing, firstProviders, 3);` is giving me an error :/

Comment: `Array.Copy(providerListing, firstProviders, 5);` gives me the error: `use of unassigned local variable 'firstProviders'`

Comment: I fixed it by giving it a blank string :)... Testing it now.

Comment: For some of the entries which had 30 providers, is currently displaying 2 while some displaying 4 while some displaying 1. I am debugging to see where the issue is.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Yea I made the assumption from the image that a provider ended at a ; if not you should change the .Split function to whatever infers a provider ends and a new one begins.